# How to hanfdle PHP 5.3.2 timezone bug?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

on server i have php 5.3.2.

if i want to run simple php script, like this :

```
<?php echo date('Y'); ?>
```

...it gives me following errors:

Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are required  to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CEST/2.0/DST' instead in /htdocs/index.php on line 9 Fatal error: date(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should never happen! in /htdocs/index.php on line 9

Timezone in php.ini is defined as Europe/London

I'm ALWAYS getting that error, despite I define or not date_default_timezone_set('UTC'), or Europe/London, or whatever...

I tried to edit /etc/init.d/httpd file, but i don't have permissions (due to selinux?)

please help...

Answer (score 1):

That's not a PHP bug - it's telling you something is wrong, and you need to correct it.

I notice the line *Timezone database is corrupt - this should never happen!* - try the following command in your shell and restart Apache: `apt-get install tzdata`.

If it's still broken after that (or you already have that package), create a new PHP file with the following contents and load it up in a browser: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

Look for **Loaded Configuration File** and check that is the php.ini file you are editing.

Open that php.ini file and look for the line beginning `date.timezone`. Make sure the timezone you are selecting is enclosed in quotes - the one I use is as follows: `date.timezone = "Europe/London"`.

Once you've modified and saved php.ini, you must reload Apache for the change to take effect.

Comment: ben, my tzdata is installed and reinstalled (yum install tzdata-2010j i run yesterday, and today yum reinstall tzdata-2010j). also in /etc/php.ini i do have line date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin". also i have edited correct php.ini (i do not have two php.ini files on my system).

Comment: and, running phpinfo(), in timezone section still have error Warning: phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CEST/2.0/DST' instead in /htdocs/info.php on line 1

Comment: and apache is of course reloaded...

Comment: to mention, i tried with Europe/Berlin, Europe/Moscow, Europe/London, also, i tried with UTC ...